# React Functional Component Re-renders exponentially with array state change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue with one of my functional components.  Basically, it has an array of messages in the state; when the server sends a new message, the state should change by pushing that new message into the array.  The issue comes as the array grows.  For each item that gets added to the array, it re-renders exponentially.  For example.  With one message in the array, it renders once, for two messages, it renders twice, for three messages, it renders six times, ect...  Normally, this would not be a huge deal.  However, in the useEffect function, I am making an api call, and for that reason, I need to limit how many times the function is called, and need to limit the render too.  Here is the code for the component, hopefully this all makes sense.  Thanks for the help!

```
// Imports here...
let count = 0;

const Chat: React.FC<any> = ({ name, chatRoom, language }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<MessageInterface>>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
        "my-custom-header": "abcd",
      },
    });

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(`I am now connected to the server with id: ${socket.id}`);
    });

    socket.emit("login", { name, chatRoom, language }, () => {});

    // unmounting
    return () => {
      socket.emit("disconnectFromServer");
      console.log("Disconnected from the server");
      socket.off();
    };
  }, [name, chatRoom, language]);

  useEffect(() => {
// ======== THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS CALLED EXPONENTIALLY======== 
    socket.on("message", (message: MessageInterface) => {
     // This is where the api call would be
      console.log(count);
      count++;
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
  }, [messages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userJoin", (usersFromServer: Array<string>) => {
      setUsers([...users, ...usersFromServer]);
    });
  }, [users]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userLeave", (usersFromServer: Array<string>) => {
      setUsers(usersFromServer);
    });
  }, [users]);

  const sendMessage = (evt: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    if (message) {
      socket.emit("sendMessage", message, () => setMessage(""));
    }
  };

  return name && chatRoom ? (
    <div id="chatOuterContainer">
      <Users users={users} language={language} />
      <div id="chatInnerContainer">
        <InfoBar chatRoom={chatRoom} language={language} />
        <Messages messages={messages} name={name} />
        <Input
          message={message}
          setMessage={setMessage}
          sendMessage={sendMessage}
          language={language}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the message listener when the `useEffect` cleans up:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (message: MessageInterface) => {
   // This is where the api call would be
    setMessages([...messages, message]);
  });
  socket.on("message", handler);
  return () => {
    socket.off("message", handler);
  };
}, [messages]);
```

A better approach would be to use the callback form, to avoid the need to depend on the outer `messages` variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (message: MessageInterface) => {
    setMessages(messages => [...messages, message]);
  });
  socket.on("message", handler);
  return () => {
    socket.off("message", handler);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  useEffect(() => {
// ======== THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS CALLED EXPONENTIALLY======== 
    socket.on("message", (message: MessageInterface) => {
     // This is where the api call would be
      console.log(count);
      count++;
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
  }, []);
```

socket.on('message',function) should only be called once. If you call it repeatedly, it will stack, not overwrite.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, looks like your solution is similar to the above.  Removing the call in the second argument helped fix it!